# Symfony Messenger not shutting down gracefully when using APP_ENV=prod

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, symfony, amazon-ecs, messenger

We are using Symfony Messenger in combination with supervisor running in a Docker container on AWS ECS. We noticed the worker is not shut down gracefully. After debugging it appears it does work as expected when using `APP_ENV=dev`, but not when `APP_ENV=prod`.

I made a simple sleepMessage, which sleeps for 1 second and then prints a message for 60 seconds. This is when running with `APP_ENV=dev`
[image]

As you can see it's clearly waiting for the program to stop running.
Now with `APP_ENV=prod`:
[image]

It stops immediately without waiting.

In the Dockerfile we have configured the following to start supervisor. It's based on `php:8.1-apache`, so that's why STOPSIGNAL has been configured

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    # for supervisor
    python \
    supervisor
```

The start-worker.sh script contains this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cp config/worker/messenger-worker.conf ../../../etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
exec /usr/bin/supervisord
```

We do this because certain env variables are only available when starting up.
For debugging purposes the config has been hardcoded to test.
Below is the messenger-worker.conf

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true               ; start in foreground if true; default false

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:messenger-consume]
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
command=bin/console messenger:consume async -vv --env=prod --time-limit=129600
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
environment=
    MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN="https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/{id}/dev- 
    symfony-messenger-queue"
```

So in short, when using `--env=prod` in the config above it doesn't wait for the worker to stop, while with `--env=dev` it does. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was related to the `wait_time` [option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#amazon-sqs) related to SQS transports. It probably caused a request that was started just before the container exited and was sent back when the container did not exist  anymore. So, `wait_time` to 0 fixed that problem.

Then there was [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/45910) which could lead to the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why there would be a difference between `dev` & `prod` environment but it seems you have no *grace period* set (at least for **Supervisor**). As I added in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#graceful-shutdown):

- the workers will be able to [handle the `SIGTERM` signal if you have the **PCNTL** PHP extension](https://github.com/symfony/messenger/blob/5.4/EventListener/StopWorkerOnSigtermSignalListener.php#L32)
- you need to add `stopwaitsecs` to your **Supervisor** program configuration

As you use **Docker** too, you can also set the [graceful period at the service level](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#stop_grace_period) which defaults to 10s:

```yaml
services:
    my_app:
        stop_grace_period: 20s
        # ...
```

With this configuration, running `docker-compose down` (just an example):

- **Docker** sends a `SIGTERM` signal to the service entrypoint (**Supervisor**) and waits 20s for it to exit
- **Supervisor** sends a `SIGTERM` signal to its programs (`messenger:consume` commands) and waits 20s for them to exit
- the `messenger:consume` processes will *"catch"* the signal, finish handling the current message and stop
- every program stopped, **Supervisor** can stop, then the **Docker Compose** stack

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In the end it turned out to be related to `RUN APP_ENV=prod APP_DEBUG=0 php bin/console cache:clear` we did before installing PCNTL, and not running the command again after the install.

The workers are no longer getting SIGKILLED, but for some reason it looks like the messages are still not acknowledged properly